# how can i search my drupal site through an api?

Tags: php, xml, json, drupal, search

im trying to implement a mobile app, and im doing a search feature for my drupal site, and i was wondering if thier is an api avaibale or do i need create one myself that will return the results in JSON or XML.

i.e im only trying to search the one type of node, the wiki pages. :)) thanks for your help, im a newbie to drupal!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services).  Tutorials and examples for this module can be found in its [Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/109782).

Answer (score 0):

Services is pretty heavy, for mobile apps I've used Views Bonus Pack's XML output format to create a view with exposed filters that returns results as XML: http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus